# How does the interval of integration change between $\int f dP$ and $\int f(x)p_X dx$?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

After reading some questions here, I now understand that the integrals $\int f(x)dP(x)$
and $\int f(x)p_X(x)dx$ are equivalent, where $P$ is the distribution of a *continuous* random variable $X$ with density function $p_X$.

My question is: Let $A$ be a measurable set and we want to find $\int_A fdP$. What will the boundary of integration be in $\int f(x)p_X(x)dx$ so that $\int_A fdP=\int^b_a f(x)p_X(x)dx$.

Comment: @geetha290krm does this mean that $A$ has to be a subset of $\mathbb{R} $?

Answer (score 1):

$\int_A fdP$ makes sense only when $A$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb R$. This becasue $P$ is a measure on the Borel sets of $\mathbb R$. [Perhaps you are confusing $P$ with the original probability measure on the space where the random variable is defined]. We do have $\int_A fdP$=$\int_A f(x)p(x)dx$ for any Borel set $A$ in $\mathbb R$.

If $X$ is a  random variable defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal F,Q)$ then the distribution $P$ of $X$ is a measure defined on the Borel sets of $\mathbb R$ by $P(B)=Q(X^{-1}(B)$. The density function $p$ of $X$  is a non-negative measurable function on $\mathbb R$ such that $P(A)=\int_A p(x)dx$ for every Borel set $A$.

Comment: What is the difference between the original measure and this measure? How are they related?

Comment: @gbd I have added the relevant definitions.

Comment: Is the difference that $P_R(A) =P_\Omega(X^{-1}(A))$?

Comment: @gbd Yes, that is correct.

Comment: When you say that "$\int_A fdP$ makes sense only when $A$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb R$", do you mean for any measure $\mu$? or only when the measure is probability measure $P$...i.e. do you mean any Lebesgue integral $\int_E fd\mu$ only when  makes sense when $E$   is a measurable subset of $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probablity space, and let $(\Psi, \mathcal{G})$  any measurable space e.g. $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})).$ Let $X:\Omega \rightarrow \Psi$ be a $\Psi$-valued random variable, then the probablity distribution $P_X$ is defined as $P_X(G):=P(\{\omega \in \Omega| X(\omega)\in \mathcal{G}\})$ for $G\in \mathcal{G}$. Note that $P_X$ is a probability measure on $(\Psi, \mathcal{G}).$ So in other words, the $P_X$ is the pushforward measure of $P$.

If we now assume that $P_X$ has a density $p_X$ w.r.t. to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$
(in the case $X:\Omega \rightarrow \Gamma \subseteq \mathbb{R}, \Psi=\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{G}=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$), then
$$
E[f(X)]=\int \limits_{\Omega} f(X(\omega)) dP(\omega)= \int \limits_{\Gamma} f(x)dP_X(x)= \int \limits_{\Gamma} f(x)p_X(x)dx
$$